# Como enviar um aplicativo Ionic para a Apple Store?

Tags: ionic

Criei um aplicativo com Ionic e quero enviar para a Apple Store. Estou seguindo esse [link](https://medium.com/@_qzapaia/deploy-an-ionic-app-to-the-ios-app-store-702c79a2dd97#.vi5swmvqc) mas paro na parte `Product>Archive`. O `Xcode` simplesmente não habilita esta opção. Como fazer ?

Comment: Desculpe a pergunta, mas já tem conta registrada como desenvolvedor na apple store? Tem os certificados para assinar o app? Achei esse tutorial muito simples, quem dera se enviar um app para apple fosse fácil assim.

Comment: tenho sim. Eu desenvolvo em iOS nativo entaum ja tenho sim. Esse eh meu primeiro projeto que faço usando framework.

Comment: neste exemplo aparece o Xcode com a opção **Archive** ativa. http://virteom.com/how-to-create-an-ipa-file-using-xcode

Comment: Aproveitando, até para eu testar o app no iOS com o Ionic/Phonegap preciso do OSX?

Comment: @DanielaMorais se estiver se referindo a testes no emulador/dispositivo, a resposta é sim, porém se não tiver um MAC e tiver um computador potente, pode instalar uma VM, eu utilizo uma para testar aplicações Xamarin.

Comment: @DanielaMorais eu contratei uma cloud para Mac pois não tenho no momento um Mac e para testar e enviar o aplicativo para a Apple apenas de um Mac. www.macincloud.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece porque você esta com alguma opção de emulador selecionado. Para poder habilitar a opção **Archive** é preciso primeiramente selecionar a opção **Generic IOS Device** na lista de emuladores:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]